# Stata: Regex search and replace on Integer variables

Tags: regex, stata

Explanation of DATA: Contains a surveyor ID and answers to various survey questions.  If one of the answers to the survey is 99 or 999 or 9999 (ad infinitum), then that is a numerical representation of "No."  If one of the answers to the survey is 98 or 998 or 988, 9988, 998888, etc., that is a numerical representation of "Yes."  Most of the data is in integer form.

I want to replace all variables that have values which start with a '9' and end with a '9' with the word "No", and all variables that start with a '9' and end with an '8' with "Yes."

My current strategy is to transform every single variable into a string `tostring _all, replace`
and then iterate thorugh all `string_vars` perform the following two regexes:

```
regexr(`value', "^[9]*[9]$","No")
regexr(`value', "^[9]*[8]$", "Yes")
```

Is there an easier way to do this without converting all values to strings?

Comment: I think you will get a better response if you explain why you would want to do this. And maybe explain your data a bit more. I assume none of it is numerical data...

Comment: I added an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check for numeric variables that are all 9s another way is

```
  ... if subinstr(string(myvar, "%20.0f"), "9", "", .) == ""
```

where 20 is a upper limit to be replaced by the longest number you need.

You can find all integer-valued variables using `findname` (`findit findname` indicates download sources).

```
 findname, all(@==int(@)) local(intvars) 
 foreach v of local intvars { 
         gen s`v' = "YES" if subinstr(string(myvar, "%20.0f"), "9", "", .) == "" 
 }
```

may be part of what you want. Are there answers other than "YES" and "NO"?

Comment: As always, the only real Stata answer.  However, I was hoping that there would be a solution without having to convert ALL the variables to strings before doing this.  Is there another way?  Right now, they're all integers.

Comment: In this solution, there is no conversion of variables to strings except what you ask for, i.e. you stipulated that you want words "Yes" "No" etc. The string operations in `if subinstr()` don't change the data.

Comment: Two questions, Nick:

1.  It's possible that the highest size integer 256, not 20.  Can the %20.0 be modified to be %256.0?  2.  Is it possible to use your subinstr technique to find integers that start with 9 followed by anywhere between one 8 or 255 8's.

Comment: To ensure that everyone reading understands, the 20 referred to number of digits, not size of integer. Your data sound extraordinary. If any variable, column or field can be a 256 digit integer, you are probably best advised to use long string variables for manipulating such beasts, which can only be done in Stata 13. I have never tried formats as big as %256.0f.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inlist` for that. var1 is the variable that contains these numbers

```
gen dummy=""
replace dummy ="NO" if inlist(var1,99,999,9999)
replace dummy ="YES" if inlist(var1,98,998,988)
```

With dummy in hand you can restrict the sample based on it.

OR,

If you don't have 0 or 1 in your var1, you can replace these with 0 and 1.

```
replace var1 =0 if inlist(var1,99,999,9999)
 replace var1 =1 if inlist(var1,98,998,988)
```

Comment: Hey Metrics, I'm not confident this is viable.  I don't know every possible configuration of numbers that the survey program will input.  It could be 999999 or 9888899, etc.  I need to make sure the first number is 9 and the last one is either 9 or 8

Comment: Do you mean each questions will have different numbers beginning with 9 and ending with 8?. In the question you said only 3.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are either only 9s or something with 8 in the end, you don't need regex here. You could simply calculate the sum of the digits and check `sum(digits) % 9`. If it's 0, your answer is `Yes`, if it's not, your answer is `No`.

Even easier would be to check `[your number] % 2`, which will always be 0 for a number ending with 8 and always be 1 for a number ending with 9.

In case, you want to only make the first and last digit count and can't be sure, they're always either 9 or 8, you'll need two regexes. Your proposed ones are good, though you can omit the `[]` around the numbers, since a character class with only one char is equivalent to the char itself. So your regexes will be
`^9*$` and `^9*8$`.

Edit:
Since it's now clear, the input will always start with a `9` and have at least two digits, it would be enough, to check `input % 10`. That way only the last digit will remain and you can check, if that's a `9` or an `8`.

Comment: I'm not sure the modulo trick will work.  I need to make sure the first number is 9, and the last number is 8 or 9  I mostly just wanted to avoid converting everything to a string, as I imagine that's a slow process.

Comment: Am I right guessing your input is always at least 2 digits? Will it always start with a 9?

Comment: It will always start with a 9.  At least 2 digits always.

Comment: I edited my answer with a possibility that should work for you.

Comment: The ideas are good but the syntax here is not Stata's, but rather some favourite language taken to be generic. The last digit of an integer in numeric form is `mod(input, 10)` and in string form is `string()` of that. The first digit of an integer is in string form `substr(string(input), 1, 1)` and in numeric form is `real()` of that. For very large integers, you might to give a format to the `string()` function in the second case.

Comment: Since you can be sure that the input will always start with a 9, you only need to check for the last digit, which is `mod(input, 10)`. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: OP leaves a little vague whether there are other non-survey questions that don't have the form discussed, so I spelled out how to check the first digit in case it is not needed, not least by other people with similar questions.